# Extract superscript and paste it into new column same row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract superscript characters (number 1 and 2) that are either in the middle or at the end of a string in column A. I need to cut them from the string and paste them into the same row, but on column C as a normal number.

My data will have always less than 500 lines and has the same structure,  but lines with superscript change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub extractSuperscript()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim result As String

    ' Define the range to process
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        Set cell = rng.Cells(i)
        result = ""

        ' Loop through each character in the cell
        For j = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
            ' Check if the character is a superscript 1 or 2
            If Mid(cell.Value, j, 1) = "¹" Or Mid(cell.Value, j, 1) = "²" Then
                ' If the character is a superscript 1, add a 1 to the result string
                If Mid(cell.Value, j, 1) = "¹" Then
                    result = result & "1"
                ' If the character is a superscript 2, add a 2 to the result string
                ElseIf Mid(cell.Value, j, 1) = "²" Then
                    result = result & "2"
                End If
            End If
        Next j

        ' Paste the result string into column C and remove the superscript from column A
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = result
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "¹", "")
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "²", "")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer. It works in part. It brings the number to column C, but as a superscript, not as a normal number. And the superscript characters stay in the strings in column A. Would you know how to address that? Many thanks again..

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code above, it now removes the superscript from column a and changes it into normal values in column C

Comment: Hi araau11, my apologies for the delay in replying. It works perfectly. OMG you helped me so much, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if the following works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Superscript()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSuperscript As Range, c As Range

Dim iCount As Integer
Dim MyString As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'Set it to sheet name where your data is
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test")

'Change it to reflect your data
Set rngSuperscript = ws.Range("A2:A11")

For Each c In rngSuperscript
    'temp text variable
    MyString = c.Value
    
    'loop through the string value
    For iCount = 1 To Len(MyString)
    
    'check if it is numeric
    If IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, iCount, 1)) Then
        'combine with the C column value (if any)
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = CLng(c.Offset(0, 2).Value & Mid(MyString, iCount, 1))
    End If
Next

Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for your answer. It did not work. A next wad missing, but even after I fixed it did not work. I also amended the range, still nothing. Thanks again..

Comment: @Yahooooooo I revised the code. What you mean by next wad? Now it should copy to C column as number. I was able to use sum formula with the extracted numbers.

Comment: Hi Vetuka, thanks again for the help. I am sorry I am only replying to it now. I meant that there was a "next" missing in the first code you gave me. Now everything is sorted. thanks again!